# The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I m trying to migrate a project initially developed using EF4 to EF6, to take advantage of EF6 transactions management.

The problem I m facing is that the project has been created using the Database First approach, so when I m using code like `context.Database.UseTransaction`, I m encountering the following error:

```
The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.
```

This exception triggers inside the `OnModelCreating` method of my `DbContext` class.

Any idea ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The thing is that it's legacy code using EDMX with database first approach. I have to implement EF6 transactions inside this project, so it should now be more like a code first pattern.

In addition, here's the context class:

```
public class MyContext : BaseDbContext
{
    public MyContext (DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }
}
```

And the connection string:

```
  <add name="CS"
         connectionString="Data Source=MyServ;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=20;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;Enlist=false"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I tried setting the `providerName` to `System.Data.SqlClient` but it doesn't change anything.

Please note that the original connection string was in the database first format:

```
<add name="OrderManagement"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyManagementModel.csdl|res://*/MyManagementModel.ssdl|res://*/MyManagementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=20;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If I try to open a connection whilst I keep the connection string in the database first format, I m facing the exception `Keyword metadata not supported`, and when I put the connection string on the code first format, I m facing the error `The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.`

Comment: check your connection string. If it doesn't contain the metadata section it is assumed to be code first, and if it does then it assumes it's edmx based. So it's possible you've got a connection string that instantiated this db context that is missing the metadata section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's where things begin getting weird. I tried both connection string formats when instantiating my dbcontext. When I use the code first approach (without the metadata section), I still get the same error mentioned above, and when I add the metadata section, it says "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'"

Comment: what's your providername set to when you have the metadata section?

Comment: It is set to "System.Data.EntityClient". I tried to set it to "System.Data.SqlClient" but it's the same.

Comment: When you are using database-first approach and you use edmx, using `OnModelCreating` makes no sense. Please add more details about the problem, for example share your context file code and say if you are using edmx and share your connection string from web config.

Comment: You should also include `BaseDbContext`. There are some problems in your configurations and codes. For example you are using `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` for code first which is a problem.

Comment: Is your BaseDBContext T4-generated?

Comment: Yes it is T4-generated

Comment: remove the `BaseDbContext` and use `DbContext` and change the provider to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`, also include the code for the `OnModelCreating` method

Comment: Did you even read my previous posts ?

Answer (score 8):

The most common mistake when converting context from database-first to code first is forgetting to remove the generated [`OnModelCreating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=entity-framework-6.2.0). In a database-first context, `OnModelCreating` throws the exception:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();  // ← throws exception
}
```

So take a look at your context or its base class (and their partial classes) and if it's like above code, you should remove it.

Also your code and configurations need some changes.

You are using `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` for a code first context. You should change the connection string to something like this:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="data source=server;
initial catalog=database;User Id=user;Password=password;
multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then you should change your context constructor to something like this:

```
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext") { /* . . .*/ }
    // . . . 
}
```

Also if you want to have a common base class, follow above instructions.

**Note:** To create code-first from an existing database, you can right click on project and choose *Add New Item*, then under *Visual C#* under *Data* select *ADO.NET Entity Data Model* and click on *Add*. Then from the *Entity Data Model Wizard* choose *Code First from Database* and follow the wizard. For more information see [Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, even when I remove the onModelCreating method, the exception is still thrown. I also tried to replace EntityClient by SqlClient in the connection string but it changes nothing. Finally, I can't modify the constructor because I need to pass a DbConnection and specify the "contextOwnsConnection" parameter.

Comment: When you remove `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` you will not receive the same exception unless you have this method in the base class too. For example the exceptions which you receive because of using wrong provider is different from the exception which you receive because of that line of code in on model creating. You should follow all instructions in the answer to get the result. Also don't neglect the *Note* part.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try when I ll have more time

Comment: If you have the entities (object) that you added manually and you want to work without an edmx file just remove OnModelCreating method from DbContext file and it will be solved

Answer (score 2):

You Have to Just Copy Connection String from App.config and Paste it into your Web.config file.

Make Sure your EDMX has updated to latest connection with database.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just connection string in web.config like this

> connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.wimEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.wimEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.wimEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=DATABASE;persist security info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"