# Setting up Entity Connection string Via Code

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Ok So I have got a bit futher with my implmentation of switching databases I have a method in my context class.

```
public string SetupConnections()
{

        //Specify the provider name, server and database.
string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        string serverName = ".";
        string databaseName = "DBNAME";

        // Initialize the connection string builder for the
        // underlying provider.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Set the properties for the data source.
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "USERNAME";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "PASS";

        // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
        Console.WriteLine(entityBuilder.ToString());

        using (EntityConnection conn =
            new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
            conn.Close();
        }
        return sqlBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

But when I run the application it is saying the underlying provider failed to open for the user am I adding in the username and password correct obv disguised my true password for security reasons.

This is my orignal connection string which works. I was following this example here from technet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-build-an-entityconnection-connection-string

And yes i no that example was intergrated security = true but I dont want to use that I want to to use username and password.

```
 <add name="SMBASchedulerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sourcenet;initial catalog=COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY;User ID=scheduler;Password=Pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am also getting this error as well I am using DB First

> : The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

I am not getting any data either i changed my entites object to as follows.

```
    public SMBASchedulerEntities(string sConnectionString)
        : base(sConnectionString)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You should remove OnModelCreating. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885636/3110834) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887186/3110834).

Comment: The entity connection string is used for database first applications, it is not required if you change the database (-> code first)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro please dont comment on a question u do not understand

Answer (score 0):

You are providing entityBuilder.Provider with "System.Data.SqlClient" but it should be "System.Data.EntityClient" to create connrction string with entity builder as per my knowledge.